# Isn't it demanding to ask for something with "Ich möchte"?

Tags: verb-usage, phrase-request, question, comparison, comparative

When they tell a waiter what food they'd like, why do Germans say "Ich möchte _" even though that translates as "I want _". Saying you want something sounds demanding in English. "I like" would be softer, but "Ich mag" seems inappropriate here for some reason.

And how does "Ich möchte" (I want) compare to "Ich mag" (I like) in terms of strength/demanding, proper situations for verb usage?

Comment: "I like to have" **ist** die passende Übersetzung. Es gibt häufig Übersetzungen, wo je nach Situation die eine Formulierung passt oder die andere, und äquivalente Ausdrücke der einen Sprache sind nicht äquivalent in der anderen. "I want cake" würde ich ins Deutsche mit "Ich will Kuchen" übersetzen, nicht mit "Ich möchte Kuchen". Mit anderen Sprachen ist das genauso.

Comment: It's different in different languages.  In Spanish, you say ''Dame una cerveza, por favor'' (literally, ''give me a beer please).  ''Me gustaría una cerveza'' would sound very unnatural and stilted.

Comment: Historically, *ich möchte* is past subjunctive of *mögen*, hence literally *I'd like*.

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong, as *mögen* = *to like* and *wollen* = *to want*.

Comment: @userunknown Jetzt aber ich doch glatt versehentlich deinen Kommentar mit einem Upvote versehen, weil ich ihn sehr treffend finde. Aber eigentlich sollte das eine Antwort sein. :/

Comment: No.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Why don't any of the answers address the question of "Ich mag"?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

"Ich möchte" doesn't really correspond to "I want", but more to something like "I would like...". "I want" would be more something like "ich will", and *that* would actually be too demanding in a restaurant situation in my opinion.

Using "ich möchte" in a situation like that may be on the more demanding side of things, but is still completely fine in my opinion. Possible alternatives are "ich hätte gerne" ("I would like to have"), "ich nehme" ("I'll take") or just your order followed by "bitte" ("please"):

> Ich möchte ein Stück Kuchen.

> Ich hätte gerne ein Stück Kuchen.

> Ich nehme ein Stück Kuchen.

> Ein Stück Kuchen, bitte.

If you consider "ich möchte" to be too demanding, you can also "soften" it with a "bitte":

> Ich möchte ein Stück Kuchen, bitte.

Same for "ich nehme":

> Ich nehme ein Stück Kuchen, bitte.

"Ich mag", by the way, isn't commonly used to order something, but more to express preference or fondness.

> Ich mag Kuchen. Ich möchte ein Stück Kuchen.

> I like cake. I would like a piece of cake.

Comment: Spot on, +1. Add to that a bit of cultural difference that Germans tend to be to-the-point and not beating around the bush, "ich möchte" is totally acceptable.

Comment: möchte is actually [cognate to English *"may"*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%B6gen), so it's pretty soft in the demand spectrum.

Comment: @RossPresser It may be helpful, though, to note that "möchten" and "may" don't have the same meaning. "Möchten" refers to the will, the want, the desire that someone has: "Ich möchte dieses Buch kaufen", "I'd like to buy this book". On the other hand, "may" is more about permission, which would put it in the vincinity of the German "dürfen": "Darf ich mir dieses Buch leihen?", "May I borrow this book?" And I wouldn't consider it _that_ soft in the spectrum, because it kind of thrusts the speaker's will on the listener. But that would be a discussion of finer graduation.

Comment: to be honest, you'd usually always add bitte so even "Ich will die Pasta bitte" doesnt sound rude or too demanding. Its a bad style, sure, but I doubt this will be frowned upon.

Comment: The infinitive form is "mögen", not "möchten", by the way. See the [other answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/67412).

Comment: @Alex “Ich will die Pasta bitte” does sound bad, like the “bitte” was just an afterthought. But “ich will” can indeed be fine with some extra soft-wrapping, e.g. “ich will gerne die Pasta probieren”.

Comment: I've been told that (at least around Dresden) people say mostly "Ich hätte gerne ..., bitte" rather than "Ich möchte ..., (bitte)".

Comment: To me, 'ich nehme' sounds more demanding than 'ich möchte' although both are fine. I've also occasionally heard 'ich kriege' but that might come over rude, so I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: "Ich möchte" is subjunctive "I would like" and that already softens it compared with the rarely heard "Ich mag" ("I like"). Also used is "Ich möchte gerne" (loosely, "I would love to have") which again makes it less of a demand.

Comment: Do people thereabouts ever order food in the form of a question? For example: "Darf ich ein Stück Kuchen haben?"

Comment: @cruthers “Darf ich ein Stück Kuchen haben?” is definitely possible, in fact a very polite phrasing. In a restaurant/bakery this would be almost a bit under-assertive – if they have cake then _surely_ they'd allow you to buy a piece! Where the question form is of course the way to go is when you really do ask whether it's possible, like “haben sie heute Steinbutt da?” And if you ask for something to drink in a non-restaurant setting then “kann ich ein Glas Wasser haben?” would be the most usual way.

Answer (score 12):

"Ich möchte" is perceived as a more polite form of "ich will", so translating both to "I want" will lose important nuance and arguably be wrong.

Grammatically, "ich möchte" is [Konjunktiv II of "ich mag"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%B6gen), as you can see by [checking a suitable dictionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%B6chte). (Even though I think that it is mostly perceived as a form of the non-existent verb "möchten", we may witness the development of a defective verb here.) So it does indeed directly correspond to "I would like".

Answer (score 10):

"Ich möchte" does not translate as "I want". It means that you have a wish, not a demand. To a waiter you would typically say "Ich möchte **bitte** das Steak" which is a bit more polite than "Ich möchte das Steak".

Already young children are taught the distinction between "ich möchte" and "ich will". Parents usually correct them when they say "ich will ein Eis" - they have to learn to say "ich möchte bitte ein Eis".

Comment: `Already young children are taught the distinction between "ich möchte" and "ich will".` Indeed. I remember the phrase "Wer will, wer will, der kriegt was auf die Brill[e]" in response to children saying "ich will".

Comment: While I fully agree with the distinction and training, I'm still baffled about some (Ober)bavarian experiences: people at the baker shop rather say "Ich bekomme ein Brot" instead of "Ich möchte ein Brot".

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is, that many Germans don't even realise it, when they sound a little demanding. Subtlety is not a German virtue. ;-)
Though Germany is a big country and it may vary by region.
To be on the safe side you can use "Ich möchte gern ..." for "I would like ...". You can also add a "Bitte" as the cherry on the top.
I wonder if being polite is being perceived as being weak by some Germans.

(These are my 5 pennies of wisdom. Btw. I consider myself as a German.)

Comment: Many people even order their food saying *Ich bekomme*.

Comment: -1 because your answer confuses literal meaning and pragmatic meaning, and because it doesn't really acknowledge how politeness actually works.